# Find email address from GAL for two people with same name

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm creating a form in Access 2016 where a user can type in an individual's name and send that individual an email.

My code will return the email address where the name is unique, however we have over 70,000 employees some of which have the same name.

```vb
Sub GetEmail() 

    Set out_App = New Outlook.Application
    Set out_NS = out_App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set out_Recip = out_NS.CreateRecipient("Gavin Thomson")

    out_Recip.Resolve

    Set out_Addr = out_Recip.addressEntry
    Set out_ExUser = out_Addr.GetExchangeUser

    MsgBox out_ExUser.primarysmtpaddress
    
End Sub
```

When I change the value to a name which exists more than once I get

> "The operation failed."

on `Set out_ExUser = out_Addr.GetExchangeUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something that you can achieve with just VBA.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only) you can create a PR_ANR restriction on the contents table of a particular search container (such as GAL). That is what Outlook does when it resolves a name you typed in the To edit box - it goes through all containers in the search path and applies the PR_ANR restriction. If there are multiple matches found, it displays a dialog box with the list. If there is a single match, it is returned and the search is stopped, otherwise it continues to the next container in the search path.

Outlook Object Model however does not expose this functionality. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language) is an option, it exposes [RDOAddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).ResolveNameEx and [RDOAddressList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).ResolveNameEx, which return a list of matches.

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.ResolveNameEx("john")
Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were retruned by ResolveNameEx:"
Debug.Print "------------"
for each AE in AdrrEntries
Debug.Print AE.Name
next
Debug.Print "------------"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've just downloaded and installed Redemption and tried it. Whilst it does list all the names, I can't see how to then pull the email addresses of individuals from that...? Perhaps I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: Relacing AE.Name with AE.smtpaddress worked perfectly.

Thanks for putting me on the right track.